# Eliminating duplicate element if the elements are on the same level in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I'm looking to display the ContributionFunds elements in the first LoanDetails element; 
ContributionFunds and LoanDetails are repeatable element so for displaying them i've made two templates;

Question: Is there a way to output the information just in the desired path ?
It doesn't matter if i will use XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

P.S. The Information from the attributes doesn't count.
Sample:

> P.P.S. It seems that all i was needed was to test the position,
>
> ```
>       <xsl:if test="position()=1">
>           <xsl:apply-templates select="../ContributionFunds"/></xsl:if>
> ```
>
> i approached the problem wrong from the start.

```
<root>
    <Data1>
        <Data2>
            <Data..>
                <ContributionFunds Amount="546548" Type="NetProceedsFromSaleOfProperty">
                    <Information../>
                </ContributionFunds>
                <ContributionFunds Amount="10000000" Type="Savings">
                    <Information../>
                </ContributionFunds>
                <LoanDetails ProductName="Variable Home Loan IO" ProductCode="VHLIO">
                    <Information../>
                </LoanDetails>
                <LoanDetails ProductName="Variable Home Loan IO" ProductCode="VHLIO">
                    <Information../>
                 <LoanDetails>
                 <Foo/>
                 <Foo.../>
            </Data..>
        </Data2>
    </Data1>
</root>
```

The output obtained if applying the template ContributionFunds in LoanDetails template

```
<root>
    <Data1>
        <Data2>
            <Data..>
                <LoanDetails ProductName="Variable Home Loan IO" ProductCode="VHLIO2">
                    <ContributionFunds Amount="546548" Type="NetProceedsFromSaleOfProperty">
                       <Information../>
                     </ContributionFunds>
                    <ContributionFunds Amount="10000000" Type="Savings">
                      <Information../>
                     </ContributionFunds>
                      <Information../>
                </LoanDetails>
                <LoanDetails ProductName="Variable Home Loan IO" ProductCode="VHLIO2">
                    <ContributionFunds Amount="546548" Type="NetProceedsFromSaleOfProperty">
                       <Information../>
                     </ContributionFunds>
                    <ContributionFunds Amount="10000000" Type="Savings">
                       <Information../>
                    </ContributionFunds>
                     <Information../>
                </LoanDetails>
                <Foo/>
                <Foo.../>
            </Data..>
        </Data2>
    </Data1>
</root>
```

The desired output

```
<root>
    <Data1>
        <Data2>
            <Data..>
                <LoanDetails ProductName="Variable Home Loan IO" ProductCode="VHLIO2">
                    <ContributionFunds Amount="546548" Type="NetProceedsFromSaleOfProperty">
                        <Information../>
                    </ContributionFunds>
                    <ContributionFunds Amount="10000000" Type="Savings">
                        <Information../>
                     </ContributionFunds>
                      <Information../>
                </LoanDetails>
                <LoanDetails ProductName="Variable Home Loan IO" ProductCode="VHLIO">
                   <Information../>
                <LoanDetails>     
                <Foo/>
                <Foo.../>
            </Data..>
        </Data2>
    </Data1>
</root>
```

For the template i've used:

```
<xsl:template match="LoanDetails">
    <LoanDetails>
        ...information
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../ContributionFunds"/>
    </LoanDetails>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template ...>
    ...

    <LoanDetailSegment CombinationLoan="{Overview/@CombinationLoan}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="LoanDetails"/>
        ...<!--other templates-->
    </LoanDetailSegment>
...
</Application>
</xsl:template><!--Not the root-->
```

Comment: The example is confusing, since it does not eliminate any duplicates in the source.  Presumably there could be more elements than shown - how does one decide which `LoanDetails` gets which `ContributionFunds`?

Comment: It doesn't decide and because of that i want to output all the ContributionFunds to the first LoanDetails.

Comment: Where does the "VHLIO2" come from? It's not in your sample input xml.

Comment: The information i've provided are sample made by me, just the structure of the elements counts;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result shown in your example could be achieved by:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Data..">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::ContributionFunds)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="LoanDetails[1]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../ContributionFunds"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I think the solution is not suited because the LoanDetails element and ContributionFunds are nested in other elements. Can this be fixed without using xsl:copy?

Comment: @DanielCSD I have adjusted my answer to your edited example. This assumes you know the name of the parent element containing the  `LoanDetails` and `ContributionFunds` elements (`Data..` in the given example). -- P.S. There's nothing wrong with using `xsl:copy`.

Comment: @DanielCSD Is your question not answered?

Comment: I've found the issue so the question is answered.Please modify because I don't know how. Thanks for your help @ michael.hor257k, i've learned a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes"/>
    <!-- identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- specific part -->
    <xsl:template match="ContributionFunds"/>
    <xsl:template match="ContributionFunds" mode="inline">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="LoanDetails[1]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="../ContributionFunds" mode="inline"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```